# Angular 6+ ngfactory.js warning while build --prod but dev build is working fine

Tags: angular, build, warnings, production

When I try to build angular for production I'm getting this error. Please let me know if there is a solution for this.

```
WARNING in ./src/app/userforms/login/login.component.ngfactory.js
149:679-708 "export 'MAT_PROGRESS_BAR_LOCATION' (imported as 'i27') was not found in '@angular/material/progress-bar'

WARNING in ./src/app/userforms/contact/contact.component.ngfactory.js
195:679-708 "export 'MAT_PROGRESS_BAR_LOCATION' (imported as 'i23') was not found in '@angular/material/progress-bar'

WARNING in ./src/app/userforms/register/register.component.ngfactory.js
218:682-711 "export 'MAT_PROGRESS_BAR_LOCATION' (imported as 'i25') was not found in '@angular/material/progress-bar'

WARNING in ./node_modules/@angular/material/progress-bar/typings/index.ngfactory.js
21:476-504 "export 'MAT_PROGRESS_BAR_LOCATION' (imported as 'i1') was not found in '@angular/material/progress-bar'

WARNING in ./src/app/home/faq/faq.component.ngfactory.js
30:331-347 "export 'MAT_ACCORDION' (imported as 'i6') was not found in '@angular/material/expansion'

WARNING in ./src/app/home/faq/faq.component.ngfactory.js
30:538-554 "export 'MAT_ACCORDION' (imported as 'i6') was not found in '@angular/material/expansion'

WARNING in ./node_modules/@angular/material/expansion/typings/index.ngfactory.js
37:372-388 "export 'MAT_ACCORDION' (imported as 'i1') was not found in '@angular/material/expansion'

WARNING in ./node_modules/@angular/material/expansion/typings/index.ngfactory.js
37:554-570 "export 'MAT_ACCORDION' (imported as 'i1') was not found in '@angular/material/expansion'

WARNING in ./src/app/members/members.component.ngfactory.js
40:484-512 "export 'MAT_PROGRESS_BAR_LOCATION' (imported as 'i3') was not found in '@angular/material/progress-bar'

WARNING in ./src/app/home/faq/faq.component.ngfactory.js
43:1451-1467 "export 'MAT_ACCORDION' (imported as 'i6') was not found in '@angular/material/expansion'

WARNING in ./src/app/members/main/dashboard/dashboard.component.ngfactory.js
55:2363-2392 "export 'MAT_PROGRESS_BAR_LOCATION' (imported as 'i14') was not found in '@angular/material/progress-bar'

WARNING in ./src/app/members/sidebar/sidebar.component.ngfactory.js
61:334-351 "export 'MAT_ACCORDION' (imported as 'i12') was not found in '@angular/material/expansion'

WARNING in ./src/app/members/sidebar/sidebar.component.ngfactory.js
61:544-561 "export 'MAT_ACCORDION' (imported as 'i12') was not found in '@angular/material/expansion'

WARNING in ./src/app/members/sidebar/sidebar.component.ngfactory.js
74:408-425 "export 'MAT_ACCORDION' (imported as 'i12') was not found in '@angular/material/expansion'

WARNING in ./src/app/members/main/dashboard/dashboard.component.ngfactory.js
76:3322-3351 "export 'MAT_PROGRESS_BAR_LOCATION' (imported as 'i14') was not found in '@angular/material/progress-bar'

WARNING in ./src/app/members/main/dashboard/dashboard.component.ngfactory.js
76:4559-4588 "export 'MAT_PROGRESS_BAR_LOCATION' (imported as 'i14') was not found in '@angular/material/progress-bar'

WARNING in ./src/app/members/main/dashboard/dashboard.component.ngfactory.js
76:5369-5398 "export 'MAT_PROGRESS_BAR_LOCATION' (imported as 'i14') was not found in '@angular/material/progress-bar'

WARNING in ./src/app/members/main/dashboard/dashboard.component.ngfactory.js
79:2406-2435 "export 'MAT_PROGRESS_BAR_LOCATION' (imported as 'i14') was not found in '@angular/material/progress-bar'

WARNING in ./src/app/members/main/dashboard/dashboard.component.ngfactory.js
79:2926-2955 "export 'MAT_PROGRESS_BAR_LOCATION' (imported as 'i14') was not found in '@angular/material/progress-bar'

WARNING in ./src/app/members/main/dashboard/dashboard.component.ngfactory.js
79:3446-3475 "export 'MAT_PROGRESS_BAR_LOCATION' (imported as 'i14') was not found in '@angular/material/progress-bar'

WARNING in ./src/app/members/main/dashboard/dashboard.component.ngfactory.js
79:5888-5917 "export 'MAT_PROGRESS_BAR_LOCATION' (imported as 'i14') was not found in '@angular/material/progress-bar'

WARNING in ./src/app/members/main/dashboard/dashboard.component.ngfactory.js
79:6491-6520 "export 'MAT_PROGRESS_BAR_LOCATION' (imported as 'i14') was not found in '@angular/material/progress-bar'

WARNING in ./src/app/members/main/dashboard/dashboard.component.ngfactory.js
79:674-703 "export 'MAT_PROGRESS_BAR_LOCATION' (imported as 'i14') was not found in '@angular/material/progress-bar'

WARNING in ./src/app/members/main/dashboard/dashboard.component.ngfactory.js
79:7632-7661 "export 'MAT_PROGRESS_BAR_LOCATION' (imported as 'i14') was not found in '@angular/material/progress-bar'

WARNING in ./src/app/members/main/dashboard/dashboard.component.ngfactory.js
86:888-917 "export 'MAT_PROGRESS_BAR_LOCATION' (imported as 'i14') was not found in '@angular/material/progress-bar'
```

Answer (score 4):

This might be due to angular-devkit are you able to update your [material module](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/11259)?

Have you tried:

- rm -rf node_modules
- npm cache verify
- npm install

mentioned [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/11394)